# Black Screen installing Ubuntu Desktop on Virtualbox on Windows 10

Tags: virtualbox

Windows 10
Virtualbox 6.0.4 
Ubuntu Desktop 18.10 64bit

When I try to start an Ubuntu virtual machine, I get the screen to select a start-up disk, but when I click the start button it goes to a black screen with two very small logos in the bottom centre. One is oblong and the other is a little man in a circle. Virtualbox seems to hang. 
I have uninstalled and installed the components several time, to no effect.

Comment: Try installing VirutalBox extension pack. It tends to do that, without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that when I had previously installed Docker for Windows it had enabled Hyper-V. Changed the Windows settings to disable it and everything is fine. Apparently Hyper-v enabled is not compatible with Virtualbox